# how can i delete every word in a text file except a word?

Tags: windows-10, text-editors, copy-paste, text-editing, text-formatting

I have a file with a bunch of info of street and WIFI(s).so i want to delete every word in the text file except ,password:********, and there is a lot of it 
and the word after password is variable/random word
a line with the word that i want to keep/copy

1499904000,::13148748,password:20022003,:1481477952,:Saad Al Ssaoudy,:7942242}]}

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you  @bertieb i have tried to import the text file into excel then selecting delimited from the text import wizard then adding (, )  in the delimiters then copying it with a mouse recorder  but it's very slow . the reason of my question is to copy the password

Comment: Do you perhaps mean ***except** password and the word immediately following it*?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include some before and after example text.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator yes

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that

Comment: @DavidPostill OK

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator done

Comment: @minamon you made a spelling error, it's except not expect. I just corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**step 1-**

find-`.*?(?=password:)(password.*?)(?=(,|\s))`
replace with- `\r\n\r\n$1\r\n\r\n`

Some explanation-  this part of the find,  `.*?(?=password:)` matches up to a point where it can lookahead i.e. immediately to the right of the cursor, and see the word password: to the right of the cursor. Then you have this part of the find, `(password.*?)` it matches and captures the word password up to, what will be mentioned next.  Then you have this part of the find `(?=(,|\s))` which says lookahead i.e. to immediately to the right of the cursor, for a comma or some whitespace like a space or end of line.  So when you look at (password.*?)  The `.*?`  part of it will go up to that point.

Say you have   [image]

note that I ticked dot matches new line when doing that regex, as the pic on imgur shows.  And notice in the pic above there are 4 passwords.

Running that find/replace, produces the following (image below)

[image]

**Step 2**

Then one only has to remove empty lines, in notepad++ one can do edit..line operations..remove empty lines

Any text editor with regex support is fine, e.g., Notepad++

Note- an earlier revision had a simpler regex that didn't deal sensibly with the string occurring multiple times(e.g. it would have just shown the last).  This solution provides all the times the string occurs.

Comment: I know we're waiting for the OP to clarify, but my guess is the word *password* appears multiple times in the file. Given you say, *"note- Try to make sure the word 'password' doesn't occur twice in the file"*, what happens/can be done if it does appear multiple times?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator  That regex would/'should' bring up the last one.  A slight adjustment, so `.*?(?=password)(password[^,]*),.*`   would get the first one.  But the ideal thing one would want if there are multiple passwords is to keep them all and remove everything else..

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator  a  solution to do that that is   two steps, (perhaps it can be done in one), though I find often doing regexes in multiple steps is the easiest and clearest way. So https://i.imgur.com/ivmzIf8.png  which says find-`(?=password:).*?(?=[\s,])`   replace with `\r\n\r\n$0\r\n\r\n`  Then every password will be on its own line. Then this  simple regexes can say any line that doesn't start with password can be cleared. so find-`^(?!password).*$` replace with (blank).

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator  note that I ticked dot matches new line when doing that regex, as the pic on imgur shows.  That produces https://i.imgur.com/tVoYscn.png  Then one only has to remove empty lines, in notepad++ one can do edit..line operations..remove empty lines.

Comment: @barlop thank you so much it worked it worked ..  i am so happy i was searching for this for a long long time . but i did the last step with EmEditor there was a problem  with notepad ++ ..  please  add the last part of the solution so that i vote it up and mark it as the best answer .

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator thank you too  `but my guess is the word password appears multiple times in the file `

Comment: @minamon done.. i've adjusted the regex a bit so that it gets a password on the last line 'cos I don't think it was before.. it's always worth testing these things

Comment: @barlop      thank you so much but there is still one last question  ... before doing the process 3491 matches of the word password are found  .. after the process is done only 3477 password are found ...why ?   here is the text file to see by yourself [link](https://ufile.io/zkjta)

Comment: @minamon i'll  look into it..  I notice that password occurs  3491 times. But `password:` occurs   3472 times.   One problem is with your data that on line 579-580   The end of line 579 says password, then it's the end of the line. Then on the next line there is a colon.  So you have some new lines in your data that shouldn't be there.  So for example if you open regular notepad make sure view..status bar is unchecked. Make sure word wrap is unchecked. Then do edit..goto line 579. Then go to the end of it You see it says password, then on the next line is a colon

Comment: i did but it says password
:EL-Samar,

Comment: @barlop  note  i have removed all "  (the Quotation mark )from the text file so i can delimit it correctly on excel that i can copy the passwords .

Comment: quotation marks won't make a difference, but I did a count for `password[\s]*:` (so password followed by any white space followed by colon), so if a colon ends up on a new line then ok. And that gets 3483 passwords. That's probably the right number.  There are times where a phrase like `password:password`  or `password:nopasswordrequired`  So it shouldn't pick up the second term password there.

Comment: it may take a little bit of fiddling to get the regex exact.. But aiming for 3483 replacements looks right.  So try this regex `.*?(?=password[\s]*:)(password.*?)(?=(,|\s))`   That catches 3484

Comment: @barlop  hi thanks it catches 3488 after doing the steps .. thanks very much.

Comment: @barlop sorry my mistake i have searched with the word password instead of  .*?(?=password[\s]*:)(password.*?)(?=(,|\s))                                    .... here is the counts of other files with the old-new regex  but with the search of the word password...............  1- 3477-3488  2- 19646-19654 3- 59532-59538  ... it improved it a little bit and that is great . many many thanks ... don't forget to edit the answer with new regex  . i am so happy that you was here to answer me 

Comment: @minamon no problem.  If you search for 'password' then if somebody has password written in their password, it will pick it up, but you don't want that.  Or if  the file  contains the words "Here are the passwords"  Then it will pick up the word password there.  So `password:` i.e. with a colon, will pick up less than `password`. But sometimes you get password then the colon is on a new line. So `password[\s]*:` is good. With more knowledge about regexes you can check for e.g. where does the word password occur without a colon after it.. So you can find discrepancies..

Comment: @minamon e.g. if you are curious where you have password followed by no colon then you could search for  eg `password(?!:)`  like sometimes you have the colon on the next line. So while searching for password can pick up too much, searching for `password:` can pick up too little. These kind of searches can find your discrepancies

Comment: @barlop  thanks very very much .. i have learned a lot from you today

Comment: @minamon no prob

Comment: @barlop    

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any program (that I have come across) which is designed for your problem.

The best thing I can suggest is writing a script using a language like Python 3.

If you are not familiar with programming, my best bet is heading to stackoverflow to present your problem.

I'm sorry if this is not a suitable alternative.

Comment: you should learn about regular expressions and capturing

Comment: @Computing Corn  yes you should